# two subscript levels in Qtextedit

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I'm trying to show text with subscript on my qtextedit:

```
ABC<sub>DEF<sub>GHI</sub></sub>
```

The problem is it works only with the first level :(
Please help!

Comment: Only a [limited subset of html](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) is supported.